# Is it possible to manage lifetime of PXGraph in Acumatica?

Tags: idisposable, acumatica

Imagine that I want to write the following code:

```
foreach (var usrRrCashBudgetItem in items)
{
    using (var graph = CreateInstance<CashBudgetItemEntry>())
    {
            graph.BudgetItem.Current = usrRrCashBudgetItem;
            graph.ApproveDocument();
    }           
}
```

If I try, compiler will say to me that it cannot implicitly convert type 'CashBudgetItemEntry' to 'System.IDisposable'.

Then let's say I try another approach:

```
((IDisposable)graph).Dispose()
```

in that case at runtime I get another error: Cannot cast 'graph' ( which has an actual type of '......' ) to 'System.IDisposable' which means that PXGraph is cilled by GC with usage of Finalizer. 
So my question is how can I manage lifetime of PXGraph in ordinary foreach loop?

Comment: Why do you want to re-instantiate the same graph over and over again in a loop? Why not just .Clear() it?

Comment: PXGraph doesnt seems to implement the Idisposable interface, so you may not be able to use it. What @Gabriel suggested is a feasible solution for you.